# Installing sIpopt on anaconda environment

Tags: pip, cygwin, anaconda, pyomo, ipopt

I am currently working on a project using an environment within anaconda (my OS is Windows). My current environment already has IPOPT installed via the anaconda cloud. Now, I am trying to install sIPOPT (a toolbox for IPOPT, not to be mistaken with IPOPT itself), available on: https://www.coin-or.org/Ipopt/documentation/node33.html.

I am trying to install sIPOPT within the same anaconda environment that I am currently using for my project. Normally, I would proceed with using conda to install packages into my environments. However, I failed to find a channel to install sIPOPT via conda, or pip.

The instructions on installation of sIPOPT only gave instructions to build the package using the linux environment, which I am not familiar with. I am now assuming that if I installed a unix-like environment like Cygwin, I would be able to install sIPOPT to my anaconda environment.

My question is: have any of you done anything similar to this? Is it possible to install sIPOPT via Cygwin to an existing conda environment with Ipopt already installed?

Many thanks! :)

Comment: You can not mix windows conda with cygwin python installation.

Comment: I see, so is there any way for me to install sIPOPT into my windows conda environment?